# Minimum permission set to enable Manage Contribution Pages?

Tags: permissions

What is the minimum set of permissions that I need to grant to a user to allow him to access 'Manage Contribution Pages'? The only permission that seems to grant access to this page is 'administer CiviCRM', but that then enables administration of essentially the entire application.

Thank you.

Comment: you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Sorry - no. Never pursued this and then handed off responsibility to others.

Comment: Keen to get a solution to this or, at least, understand why it's like this. Seems odd that I can grant permission for a user to manage Event pages but can't do the same with Contribution pages.

Comment: I know this is old, but checking out the documentation for hook_civicrm_aclGroup or hook_civicrm_permission may be helpful in creating an extension that can do this for you. I'm not sure if you can override permissions on the fly when a user is viewing a page.

Comment: @Sleewok hook_civicrm_aclGroup  hook is limited to following civicrm entities and contributions is not included in them:
civicrm groups, profiles and events

Documentation: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_aclGroup/

Comment: What CMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Administer CiviCRM includes administering Contribution pages. You can create a role for administering the CRM (such as editor) and then actually restrict menu items to that same role so that they don't have easy access to everything else. However, it would be pretty hard to make a contribution page without being able to access nearly all the other settings.

Managing the contribution pages is a higher function.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create/edit contribution pages you will need to give `CiviCRM: access CiviCRM` permission but that will also give them ability to control almost all of the backend. In order to give them ability to record backend contributions (with edit contributions) and view all contributions (for visible contacts), you can give them `CiviContribute: access CiviContribute` permission.